# Filtering out one object from a list of objects based on a field using jq

Tags: json, jq

We have the following json file , that include partitions and partition id )

in the file we have 6 partitions , while topic name is the same on all partitions

```
more file.json

{
  "version": 1,
  "partitions": [
    {
      "topic": "list_of_cars",
      "partition": 2,
      "replicas": [
        1003,
        1004,
        1005
      ],
      "log_dirs": [
        "any",
        "any",
        "any"
      ]
    },
    {
      "topic": "list_of_cars",
      "partition": 4,
      "replicas": [
        1005,
        1006,
        1001
      ],
      "log_dirs": [
        "any",
        "any",
        "any"
      ]
    },
    {
      "topic": "list_of_cars",
      "partition": 0,
      "replicas": [
        1001,
        1002,
        1003
      ],
      "log_dirs": [
        "any",
        "any",
        "any"
      ]
    },
    {
      "topic": "list_of_cars",
      "partition": 1,
      "replicas": [
        1002,
        1003,
        1004
      ],
      "log_dirs": [
        "any",
        "any",
        "any"
      ]
    },
    {
      "topic": "list_of_cars",
      "partition": 5,
      "replicas": [
        1006,
        1001,
        1002
      ],
      "log_dirs": [
        "any",
        "any",
        "any"
      ]
    },
    {
      "topic": "list_of_cars",
      "partition": 3,
      "replicas": [
        1004,
        1005,
        1006
      ],
      "log_dirs": [
        "any",
        "any",
        "any"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to print the following according to partition id

For example

Lets say we want to print the json part for partition id – 4

Then expected results should be like this

```
{
           "topic": "list_of_cars",
           "partition": 4,
           "replicas": [
                          1005,
                          1006,
                          1001
           ],
           "log_dirs": [
                          "any",
                          "any",
                          "any"
           ]
}
```

**the best case is to print the following valid format ( if it possible )**

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "partitions": [{
        "topic": "list_of_cars",
        "partition": 4,
        "replicas": [
            1005,
            1006,
            1001
        ],
        "log_dirs": [
            "any",
            "any",
            "any"
        ]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job of simple filter in `jq` to select the required object from the list of objects.

```
jq --arg part_id "4" '.partitions[] | select(.partition == ($part_id|tonumber))'
```

or use the `map()` function

You can feed the required partition id as input and later use that in the `select(..)` expression. Since by default the args are evaluated as strings and the filter needing an integer value to be checked, we do a string to input conversion using `tonumber`, so that the `.partitition` is compared against an integer value.

To answer the follow up question to retain only the object needed and remove the other ones, use the `|=` operator and select

```
jq --arg part_id "4" '.partitions |= map(select(.partition == ($part_id|tonumber)))'
```

Comment: thank you so much ( +1 )  , I update my question with - the best case is to print the following valid format ( if it possible ) , is it possible to change you jq syntax in order to print  what I wort in "best case" , or maybe to add some bash additional steps ?